# Java StringBuffer, ASCII characters and serial communications

Tags: java, string, serial-port, buffer

I'm developing a Java application which has to receive messages from a serial bus device.

My intent was to use `StringBuffer`s to handle those messages, but there's something I have to consider: messages could contain non-printable characters (e.g. 0x02).

Due to that, I was effectively wondering if StringBuffer objects are a good fit to handle such data, or do they have some limitations related to the range of characters they can accommodate and if so what object would be appropriate? Or maybe `byte[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use StringBuffer.

As Alex mentioned, it consists of a sequence of Char, where every Char represents 16 bit unicode value.

Alternatively, if thread safety is not required, I would recommend to use **StringBuilder** instead. StringBuilder is not thread safe and is much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure why exactly you would want to use a StringBuffer over something more generic like a byte[] or bytebuffer as giorashc mentioned, but...

a StringBuffer is essentially a String. Strings are backed by an array of the `char` primitive type. in java, a `char` is a 16 bit unicode value giving it a range of 0x0000 to 0xFFFF (65,535).